# How prove $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{PA+PB}\ge 2\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}h_{a}}$

Tags: geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

**Question:**

> Consider a triangle $\Delta ABC$ with altitudes $h_{a}$, $h_{b}$ and $h_{c}$, where $AB=c$, $BC=a$ and $AC=b$.
> Show that for any $P$
>
> $$\sqrt{PA+PB}+\sqrt{PB+PC}+\sqrt{PA+PC}\ge 2\sqrt{h_{a}+h_{b}+h_{c}}$$

[image]

My try: the inequality is equivalent to

$$(PA+PB+PC)+\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(PA+PB)(PB+PC)}\ge 2(h_{a}+h_{b}+h_{c})$$

Comment: To confirm: $h_a$, $h_b$, and $h_c$ are the altitudes in $\triangle ABC$, and are not altitudes from $P$ in the subtriangles?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt,Yes,Thank you

Comment: @chinamath Did you try an analytic approach? Say, A is the origin and $B=(B_1, B_2)$, $C = (C_1, C_2)$. Since a triangle is convex you can describe it by two parameters $s$, $t > 0$ and every point $Q$ inside the triangle is given as $Q = s \cdot \vec{AB} + t \cdot \vec{AC}$ with $s + t = 1$. The sum of the heights can be expressed through $a$, $b$, $c$. The only thing left to do is find all the local and global minima of the expression on the left-hand sinde within the triangle. It is cumbersome and not elegant at all, but it should get the job done.

Comment: @chinamath have you an idea when the sign of equality holds ?

Comment: equality holds at the center of an equilateral triangle

Comment: Things one can assume without loss of generality:

\begin{align}
A&=(0,0)\\
B&=(1,0)\\
C&=(x,y)\text{ with $y>0$}\\
P&=(p,q) \text{ lies in $\triangle ABC$}
\end{align}

The last one in particular implies $0\leq q \leq y$ and $py-qx\geq 0$.

It's possible to reduce the statement inequality to a polynomial inequality in $PA,PB,PC, h_a,h_b$ and $h_c$, but it's a rather involved expression and I'm not sure it's of much use.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the LHS is dependent on $P$ but the RHS isn't. So why not try the following approach: Find out the $P$ for which the LHS is minimum , and prove the inequality. Then we are done!

For any given triangle $ABC$, the minimum value of LHS will occur if the $P$ is the Circumcentre. i.e. $PA=PB=PC=R\ (circumradius)$. The inequality reduces to
$$ 9R\ge 2(h_a+h_b+h_c)$$ Now we know $R,h_a,h_b,h_c$ in terms of the sides and angles. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: The last inequality should not be too tough. It's the minimum part that's one should pay attention to though.

Comment: Exactly: why the minimum of the LHS occurs at the circumcentre? I think that is not true.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : Won't AM-GM inequality help?